# Cannot pass parameter 1 by reference (Virtuemart 3.2.1) + Joomla! 3.8.11

Tags: javascript, php

[Error img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HpK9.jpg)

I have problem with wrong code.

```
if (typeof callback == 'function') {
        http_ask.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (http_ask.readyState == 4) {
                if (http_ask.status == 200) {
                    result = http_ask.responseText;
                    callback(result);
                } else {
                    alert('Send failed');
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    http_ask.send(params);
```

How can i fix this. On php 5.6 everything was ok. When i have changed php vr. to 7.1 the code crashed

Comment: Wrong question. Looks like you have problems with PHP, not JavaScript. Check server-side code.

Comment: Can you be more precise? What is crashing? Provide the error message.

Comment: FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  Missing boundary in multipart/form-data POST data in Unknown on line 0" while reading response header from upstream